# Metadata API ConnectionException

Tags: api, metadata

I'm getting a ConnectionException when attempting to execute the following line of code:

```
metadataConnection.readMetadata("CustomObject", StringUtils.split("Shipment__c"));
```

However, I am able to read almost any other object from the Org.  Some objects fail, and the only thing I can think is that the objects that are failing have a lot of fields.  Is there a maximum size of the XML that can be returned by the Metadata API?  The actual exception is:

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...</fullName><displayLocationInDecimal>... @98:32324
```

Comment: unable to find end tag at:  START_TAG seen ...</fullName><displayLocationInDecimal>... @98:32324

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce's metadata.wsdl appears to be incorrect. I was able to resolve this issue by making the following changes to metadata.wsdl before running it through WSC.

Add the following line to FieldType:

```
<xsd:enumeration value="Location"/>
```

Add the following line to CustomField, under displayFormat:

```
<xsd:element name="displayLocationInDecimal" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean"/>
```

Comment: It's 2021 and still salesforce hasn't added ,issed property in its Metadata WSDL -_-. Thank you very much for the answer!